# webservice: error in code or connection

Tags: java, mysql, database, service

I have a problem in my code or connection I think...

I tried to connect to a MySQL database and web service, but when I run the program, it gives me the following error:

[alt text http://www6.0zz0.com/2009/04/17/13/808603628.jpg](http://www6.0zz0.com/2009/04/17/13/808603628.jpg)

> @WebService()
>   public class LostNumWebService {

```
/**
 * Web service operation
 */
@WebMethod(operationName = "getCategory")
public List getCategory(@WebParam(name = "city_name")
String city_name) {
    List cityName = null;
    try{
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mobileapplication";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"***","***");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs;
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT city_id, city_name FROM city WHERE city_name = $city_name");
        while ( rs.next() ) {
            String lastName = rs.getString("city_name");
            cityName.add(lastName);
           // System.out.println(lastName);
        }
        conn.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage()); 
    }


    return cityName;
}
```

I don't know what's the error, the connection or the code?
Can i get some help here, please?

Comment: You need a finally statement to clean up your database connection amongst other things.

Answer (score 2):

I guess "www.localhost.com" should be simply "localhost"; this often happens if the server is not responding, Firefox attempts to search the server on the net. Are you sure the port number is correct?

**NOTE#1**: which appserver/webservice platform are you using? Did you write a client or are you trying to use the default automatically generated client?

**NOTE#2**: when your code will be invoked it will most likely throw a "null pointer exception" here

> cityName.add(lastName);

because you forgot to initialize the list, and it may never find your city because you forgot to set the parameter

> $cityName

before invoking the preparedStatement.

**NOTE#3**: you'd better test the web service invocation and the code it is executing in two different steps; consider writing a simple main or a test case for the latter.

Comment: I tried to change the port# as i have 
http://localhost:3306/TheLostNumberApplication/faces/welcomeJSF.jsp
but it still doesn't work ...

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced that before, but that was my DNS messing things up.

Answer (score 0):

A few tips...

You should probably figure out where the error output from your program ends up.
Typically, when running things in a servlet container (tomcat?) the server writes stdout and stderr to files (maybe in logs?) Also, find out how the application server/container logs exceptions.

Maybe you should try to run your code as a regular java application first.

When catching an exception, it's probably a good idea to use a logging framework  to log the exception. Either log4j or java.util.logging will do.

...or - just for testing, do a exception.printStackTrace() so that you get the full 
information.

Also, the SQL query is'nt good... Look up PreparedStatement for dynamic parameters.

```
if( city_name == null ) {
  //return nothing?
} else {
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT city_id, city_name FROM city WHERE city_name = ?");

   pstmt.setString(1, city_name); /// 

 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Manrico said; you are not connecting to you web server.

Change the url to "http://127.0.0.1:17978/LostNumApplication"  and try again.

If that doesn't work it might be a firewall, or maybe the server is running on a different port.

If it's tomcat, check server.xml.